# Thymeleaf if expression not working with theme param value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a theme resolver in my application. There are two themes: dark and white.

```
<p th:text="${param.theme}">

</p>
```

This returns the current theme, dark or white. However, the

```
<p th:if="${param.theme == 'white'}">
    white theme
</p>
```

outputs nothing.

I want this to implement theme switching. How to make it work?

The Java configuration code.

```
public class WebConfig  implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        var templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

        var templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        var resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        var registry = new ViewResolverRegistry(null, applicationContext);

        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThemeSource themeSource() {

        var themeSource = new ResourceBundleThemeSource();
        themeSource.setBasenamePrefix("themes/");
        return themeSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThemeResolver themeResolver(){

        var resolver = new CookieThemeResolver();
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(604800);
        resolver.setCookieName("mytheme");
        resolver.setDefaultThemeName("dark");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        var themeChangeInterceptor = new ThemeChangeInterceptor();
        themeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("theme");
        registry.addInterceptor(themeChangeInterceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your java code as well?

Comment: Added the Java configuration code.

Comment: this mean your param.theme different than 'white' , try with the inverse ,waht it outputs ? 
`${param.theme != 'white'}`

Comment: @BooBerr'ita If I do `!=` than it outputs content in both cases.

Comment: so the theme is dark in this case ? you want to implemnt one link switching depending on actual theme ?

Comment: wasn't it `eq` instead of `==` in the `Thymeleaf`?

Comment: @BooBerr'ita yes, I want switching based on actual theme. What happens is that I get both links to switch with `!=`. It looks like it is not a string but some other object. 
@Pijotrek `eq` is an alias for `==`. Same issue.

Comment: @JanBodnar try accessing theme name using `RequestContextUtils.getTheme( request ).getName()` as follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to convert theme param to string ( using thymleaf expression #{} ) and then compare it to your theme name

as below :

```
<p th:if="${#strings.toString(param.theme) == 'white'}">
    white theme
</p>
```

Comment: Now it works. I wonder why we need this conversion; what kind of object the `param.theme` is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
     public class DataInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
      {
            @Override public void postHandle( HttpServletRequest request, 
           HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView 
             modelAndView ) throws Exception
           {
    if( modelAndView != null )
    {
        setup( modelAndView.getModel(), request );
    }
}

              private void setup( Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request )
                         {
                    String theme = RequestContextUtils.getTheme( request ).getName();
                         model.put( "theme", theme);

                             }
      }
```

Comment: There is already a `ThemeChangeInterceptor` which should be doing this. Also I think that the `setup` method is not called.

Comment: modified my answer

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion gave me some hints.